# How long would it take for society to reform?

Tags: society, humans, post-apocalypse

In this scenario, all of humanity spontaneously disappears. Earth is left untouched for a while, but not for too long. Buildings stay mostly completely intact, and most importantly, so does the internet. One day, Earth is repopulated with humans, just as intelligent, but with no memories of Earth. How long would it take for them to reform society, with all the access to past humanity? I'm not saying I want a perfect recreation, just *A* society, whether it be completely different or not.

Comment: What knowledge *do* the new humans have? If they don't have language then they won't last long, but human language ought to count as "knowledge from Earth" since Earth is the only place human languages are spoken. Likewise, do they know that tin cans contain food, and do they know how to open them?

Comment: It's not hard to find out how to smash open a can on a rock. Since many cans have photos on them, i can imagine they'd figure it out.

Comment: As for language, there are still perfectly working recordings everywhere, scattered about themeparks and billboards, like babies, they'd likely learn through osmosis.

Comment: Yes, if you know there is food in it then you can figure out how to open it. But you'd have to know that the pictures on the cans show food. How do you figure that out if you've never seen a bean or a cooked meal before? I think the hard part is how they survive the first week, but you seem to take that for granted.

Comment: How is this question 'Too Story-Based'? Can someone who VTCed it as such explain their reasoning?

Answer (score 7):

Without memories of Earth I doubt the repopulated humans ability to survive more than a few weeks, possibly even days. Intelligence is fine and all but without baseline knowledge of how to apply it to the current situation it's pretty useless.

For example, your repopulated human gets thirsty and drinks the nearest water which just happens to be salt water, Doesn't  help at all. Or has other pollutants. Turning preserved foods into something edible is also not always a straightforward process. Non-preserved foods are an even bigger hurdle.

Comment: Ancient humans managed to evolve into us, facing such similar hurdles

Comment: They had parents to teach them how to survive.

Comment: And they were genetically adapted for their environment. Humans are not *genetically* adapted for the modern world, because the modern world hasn't existed long enough for us to genetically adapt to it.

Answer (score 2):

The internet remains operational?  How is that supposed to happen?

Take away the humans, pretty soon the coal-fired powerplants start running out of fuel.  They shut down.  The grid control computers scream but there's nobody there to cut off loads in a graceful fashion.  Other plants get overloaded and start dropping off--the damage goes faster and faster.  The nuke plants fare the worst, once they trip they will try to draw power from the grid, then they'll resort to their backup generators.  Those backup generators will in time run out of fuel and the reactors go Fukushima.

The internet computers fall back onto batteries and backup generators but the fuel is no more than days before they shut down.  At this point all the hardware is still there but your newcomers have no way to bring it back up.  (And even if you put the original humans back they're not going to be able to bring it back up--nobody's going to get the grid together before civilization collapses and most everyone dies.)

Comment: Correct. Within a few days, the internet begins to fail. There are too many dependencies that need human management and control, not automated. Power ceases in too many places over a few days too. Beyond that, within a short time (weeks to months) certificates fail and communications dont work - much of the modern internet is SSL only based, DNS breaking down. Over a slightly longer period, major cables arent maintained and fail, nearline and most cloud data stores fail, that stuff is largely on spinning HDDs not SSD with edge caching; the caches work but the backing end doesnt. And so on.

Comment: I think this is overstating it; many places which operate servers use no coal power whatsoever for their grid (e.g. [the UK](https://grid.iamkate.com/)). The question also says Earth is left *"untouched for a while, but not for too long"*, so we ought to interpret this as meaning a short enough time that the internet still works. If that's just one day, then so be it.

Comment: @kaya3 I just focused on coal because it's the one that goes first.  And even one day doesn't matter--the new occupants will not know how to keep the system running.  Without **skilled** operators the grid will crash.  All the sources of power need maintenance, that's not going to get done.

Comment: Sure, but it will fail after the new arrivals.

Comment: @kaya3 Even if it's after the new arrivals the problem remains--the grid goes down and takes down the internet.  My point is that the internet-stays-up part of the question isn't within the realm of possibility.  You need a lot of people with a lot of different skills to keep the grid up.

Answer (score 2):

**Two days**

Three humans realize they are alive. They spend one day trying to figure out what to do and find out they need food, water, and shelter. One hunts, one gets water, and one makes shelter. On day two they all share the results of their labors. They now have a primitive society.

**One year**

If books are intact then there are million of books that teach your local language to people with no language experience: babies. One of the people sees this book and realizes the scribbles match, and this book has pictures. Once they crack a language they can read anything, giving them access to technical manuals and the internet. Any local group that doesn’t discover language will be conquered by someone who has in a year.

Answer (score 1):

They probably don't reform society. With no real knowledge of survival, the vast majority die quickly from exposure, wild animals, or accidents, and those that remain form primitive tribes that have no real idea of what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

They won't re-form today's society. They will have their own society. They will make up stories as to why the "people from long ago" lived in such strange places with strange symbols. (Like how the people created stories about those abandoned cliff dwellings.)

In order to survive earth, they will have their own technology based on what they have previously learned. Most likely, they will be a hunter-gatherer society using stone tool technology. They would be able to use glass to make tools and might scavenge glass from cities.

Cities will not be thought of as places to live until population density got to where they could congregate and do trade. Thus, the Internet will not help them. Old knowledge (such as can be found on the Internet) only helps when people can specialize in knowledge. Until then, every able body is focused on finding food. (See the "dark ages" in Europe.)

One thing to keep in mind. If all of today's humans disappeared, the natural cycle of weather will reestablish itself. Our warming of the planet started 10,000 years ago. Based on the normal cycles, we should be part way to a new ice age right now.  So, they would face very different climate than what we face.